# configure eclipse with tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have opened an existing project into eclipse, Project files are located at `C:\CodeFiles`
I have tomcat instance configured on port 80 and is at location `C:\bin\tomcat-6.02`

I am working on amazon ec2 machine and I can access my tomcat webapps from internet via url `http://somestaticip.com/`

I want to edit files in eclipse, automatically updated to tomcat instace at C:\bin\tomcat-6.02 how to configure eclipse to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this tutorials might helpful to [you](http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-eclipse). and this [also](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html).